# Formal name for left/right-hand-side of an expression

Tags: terminology

Given an expression, such as `int x = y + 5`, we'd call `int x` the `left-hand side` (or `LHS`), and `y + 5` the `right-hand side` (or `RHS`). The whole expression is called, of course, an `expression` (or `equation`), but is there a generic term for a "side" of an expression?

`LHS` and `RHS` don't quite cut it when it comes to an expression such as `int x = y = 5` (gloss over the fact here that such assignments are generally bad practice!).

I'm toying with the term `component` to describe any "side", but was interested to see if there was a formal standard term already in use. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sides_of_an_equation) only has "Sides of an equation", any better suggestions?

Comment: in which language would "int x = y = 5" work? I would assume the use of parentheses would clarify evaluation order and hence, LHS and RHS. http://www.itu.dk/courses/BPRD/E2009/fundamental-1967.pdf is about as authorative as it comes...

Comment: It's a general statement, none of this is in a particular language - I've seen such statements in a few languages, C# and Java come to mind *I think* but it's been a while since I touched either, so might not have been those - have definitely seen it used (and warned against) before though. Although it's not something I ever use myself. I think (don't quote me - like I say, it's not something I ever personally use) the flow is the same as `y = 5; int x = y;`.

Comment: The point was the terms LHS and RHS doesn't work so well when there are 3 "sides" to an expression, and it seems there ought to be be a none-side-specific term for each "chunk" of an equation. As in, the LHS and RHS are collectively an ... [insert answer here]. 'chunk' or 'component' or 'part' are the best terms I have so far.

Comment: @Kai (*et al*) the term *term* suggests itself.

Comment: I don't think there is a standardised word. If you need to describe this type of situation, a definition using a name of your choice (chunk,term,part) preceding an usage would suffice, I imagine.

Comment: there's also a LHS and RHS for any binary operator, so `x=y+5` has 3 sub expressions (2 of which get coalesced into the RHS of the assignment), it just depends on the scope and context

Comment: Are you thinking of "lvalue" and "rvalue" ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues

Comment: Nope - I'm after *a single term* that can be used to described *either*. High Performance Mark has the best one so far.

Comment: Note, functional languages, including c#'s lambda system, allow the RHS to contain another expression that has its own RHS and LHS.  ( Msdn.microsoft.com )

int oddNumbers = numbers.Count(n => n % 2 == 1);.....just FYI so when you go about defining what RHS is in Backus-Naur the definition is recursive.

Comment: Assuming a C-like language syntax, the code `int x = y + 5` is not an expression, it is a variable declaration and initialization. This is a statement, not an expression. The part on the left side is a variable declaration. Only the part to the right of the `=` is an expression. There is no common name for these two "parts" since they are not interchangeable on any level. But if the code was `x = y + 5`, it would be an assignment expression and each side an operand (which is also an expression).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you're looking for the word *[operand](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operand)*. A unary operator has one operand. A binary operator has two operands; if the operator is infix, i.e. if the expression is written horizontally with the operator between the two operands, then the operands are known as the *left-hand side* and *right-hand side* (very commonly abbreviated LHS and RHS). There are other names when the operator is written differently, for example *numerator* and *denominator* for the fraction operator arranged vertically and marked by a horizontal bar. A ternary operator has three operands (which don't have standard names; if they're written from left to right, you might call them left, middle and right operand), and so on.

Assuming C, `x ? y : z` has three operands for the `?:` operator which are `x`, `y` and `z`. The syntactic element `int x = y = 5` is not parsed as an expression with a single operator; `x`, `y` and `z` are *subexpressions* but so is `y = 5`. `y` and `5` are operands of the operator `=`. There is no generic term to designate `x` and `y = 5` here: in general parsing terminology, they are operands of the declaration operator, but in C terminology, the word *operand* is reserved for things that C calls *operators*.

If you want to treat `int _ = _ = _` as a single unit (which isn't how C syntax works), you can refer to the pieces as the left, middle and right subterms.

The word *subterm* can be used more or less interchangeably with *subexpression* in general parsing literature, but specific languages often make a difference between the two (often an expression is a particular kind of term, but occasionally it's the opposite). You can refer to subterms which are one step down from a node in the parse tree as *immediate subterms*.

A term that cannot be decomposed any further is an *atom*.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC from my high school days (some SIXTY years ago!), the left-hand side was called the comparator, and the right-hand side was called the "comparand".

Comment: Wouldn't this terminology apply only when comparison is being expressed (and not other kinds of operation)?